# How to mask values in column based on a condition per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'ID_1':['A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'ID_2':[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2],
        'DATE':['2021-11-21', '2021-12-19', '2021-09-05', '2021-11-07', '2021-12-05','2021-12-26'],
        'VALUE': [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I would like to leave value in column `'VALUE'` only for lowest date from column `'DATE'` for subset of `'ID_1'` and `'ID_2'`
Desired output look like this:

```
data = {'ID_1':['A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'ID_2':[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2],
        'DATE':['2021-11-21', '2021-12-19', '2021-09-05', '2021-11-07', '2021-12-05','2021-12-26'],
        'VALUE': [0.5, np.NaN, 0.5, 0.6, np.NaN, 0.6]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I tried is to create function which twice grouping this dataframe but I'm ending with ValueError `Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)`

My function:

```
def foo(val):
    
    def add_mask(val):
        val.reset_index(inplace=True)
        min_date = val['DATE'].min()
        mask = val.DATE == min_date
        return val[mask]
    
    return val.groupby('ID_1').apply(add_mask)

test = df.groupby('ID_2').apply(foo)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your two ID columns and compute the min with [`transform('min')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the data where the value is not equal:

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].mask(df['DATE'].ne(df.groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2'])['DATE'].transform('min')))
```

output:

```
  ID_1  ID_2        DATE  VALUE
0    A     1  2021-11-21    0.5
1    A     2  2021-12-19    NaN
2    A     2  2021-09-05    0.5
3    B     1  2021-11-07    0.6
4    B     1  2021-12-05    NaN
5    B     2  2021-12-26    0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby` "ID_1" and "ID_2" and transform the `min` of "DATE" for each group for the DataFrame. Then use `eq` to identify the rows where the group mins exist. Finally, use `where` to assign NaN values to "VALUE"s that are not min:

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].where(df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2'])['DATE'].transform('min').eq(df['DATE']))
```

Output:

```
  ID_1  ID_2        DATE  VALUE
0    A     1  2021-11-21    0.5
1    A     2  2021-12-19    NaN
2    A     2  2021-09-05    0.5
3    B     1  2021-11-07    0.6
4    B     1  2021-12-05    NaN
5    B     2  2021-12-26    0.6
```

Function `foo` doesn't work because you never use `mask` you create in it to modify "VALUE" in each group. If you replace

```
return val[mask]
```

with

```
val['VALUE'] = val['VALUE'].where(mask)
return val
```

it will produce the expected outcome (you'll need to fix the index but the general structure will be what you expect).

Answer (score 0):

Many elegant answers, but here is how I will go about it;

```
grp = df.groupby(["ID_1", "ID_2"])
grp

def change(df):
    df.loc[df.DATE != df.DATE.min(), 'VALUE'] = np.nan
    return df

grp.apply(change)
```

Results in:

```
    ID_1    ID_2    DATE    VALUE
0   A   1   2021-11-21  0.5
1   A   2   2021-12-19  NaN
2   A   2   2021-09-05  0.5
3   B   1   2021-11-07  0.6
4   B   1   2021-12-05  NaN
5   B   2   2021-12-26  0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it:

```
df['DATE'] = df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).DATE.transform(lambda x: (x==min(x))*x).replace('', np.NaN)
```

Using the boolean `(x==min(x))`:

```
df['is_min'] = df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).DATE.transform(lambda x: x==min(x))
#
#   ID_1  ID_2        DATE  VALUE  is_min
# 0    A     1  2021-11-21    0.5    True
# 1    A     2  2021-12-19    0.5   False
# 2    A     2  2021-09-05    0.5    True
# 3    B     1  2021-11-07    0.6    True
# 4    B     1  2021-12-05    0.6   False
# 5    B     2  2021-12-26    0.6    True
```